# Proving that if $3| x$ and $5|x$, then $15|x$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, divisibility

> Prove if $3| x$ and $5|x$, then $15|x$.

I'm thinking the answer will have something to do with either the fact that both $3$ and $5$ are prime, or that $15$ is the lowest common multiple of $3$ and $5$, but I'm not sure how to use those facts in the proof.

Answer (score 3):

Write $x=3k=5j$. Then $3|5j$. Since $3\not\mid 5$ we have that $3|j$ since $3$ is prime. Hence $x=5\cdot 3\cdot j'=15j'$. Hence $15|x$.

Comment: Not "$15\mid j$" but "$15\mid x$"

Comment: @Joffan ah, I see, thank you! All the | to \mid changes made me think it was just some typesetting changes, I will fix that.

Comment: You could do worse than look at the edit reason tag ;-)

Answer (score 0):

From the fact that $y$ divides $x$ and $z$ divides $x$ you cannot infer that $yz$ divides $x$: $3$ divides $6$ and $3$ divides $6$, but $9$ does not divide $x$.  But you're close: it's the fact that $3$ and $5$ are *co-prime* that makes their product divide $x$.

Comment: It **is** the fact that both are prime since they are distinct (a lemma is needed to extend this to the case $\gcd(m,n)=1$) for general $m,n$

Answer (score 0):

Just use the danged definitions.

$3|x$ means that there is some $k$ so that $x = 3k$ and $5|x$ means that $x=5j$ for some $j$.  So $3k = 5j$ so $k = \frac{5j}3$ is an integer.  But $3$ and $5$ have no factors in common, so $3|j$. so $j = 3m$ for some $m$.  So $x = 5j = 5*3*m = 15m$.  So $15|m$.

Comment: That last one isn't definition, there is a lemma that says $a|bc\implies a|b$ or $a|c$ if $\gcd(b,c)=1$. It's only definition if $a$ is prime.

Comment: The last what isn't a definition?  What is only a definition if $a$ is prime?

Comment: "But 3 and 5 have no factors in common." It appears you are trying to use this to conclude $3\cdot 5|x$, which is a lemma, not a definition.

Answer (score 0):

If $3$ and $5$ divide $x$, the latter is a common multiple of $3$ and $5$, hence a multiple of $\;\operatorname{lcm}(3,5)$. Now, since $3$ and $5$ are coprime,
$$\operatorname{lcm}(3,5)=3\cdot 5.$$